# How to show a shorten date in a ng-repeat) (Ionic-Framework)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to show a list of products of an array. The array has a name(pname) and a date(date) to each product.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="object in products" href="#/app/fridge/{{object.pname}}">
    <b>{{object.pname}}</b> <a id="date">{{objectdate}}</a>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

If I do it in this way, the date is shown in a very unlucky way. How can I fix this?

Maybe you can tell me, how I can write the period between the given date und the today's date.

I already tried this but it doesnt work:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="object in products" href="#/app/fridge/{{object.pname}}">
  <script>
  var date = object.date;
  //some steps to short the date...
  var shortDate = ...
  </script>
    <b>{{object.pname}}</b> <a id="date">{{shortDate}}</a>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I hope you can follow my description. This is my first question here.. :)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you show an example of what the date looks like when it is shown?

Comment: "2016-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
its a DateTime but I only need the date.

Answer (score 0):

Use moment(http://momentjs.com/) library and angular-moment adapter(https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) to solve this.

it's very easy to use:

```
<b>{{object.pname}}</b> <a id="date">{{object.date|amTimeAgo}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the built-in date filter: {{object.date | date: 'shortDate'}}

Look at the different formats in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Answer (score 0):

Then you only need the date filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="object in products" href="#/app/fridge/{{object.pname}}">
    <b>{{object.pname}}</b> <a id="date">{{ object.date | date:'shortDate' }}</a>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other filter about using the filter date are good.

I'm just answering because a comment wouldn't be easy to read for this.
This code won't ever work :

```
<script>
var date = object.date;
//some steps to short the date...
var shortDate = ...
</script>
```

You must move this code in your angular's controller and store the value in the scope : 
    $scope.shortDate =

However for this kind of things using filters are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function inside your item:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="object in products" href="#/app/fridge/{{object.pname}}">
    <b>{{object.pname}}</b> <a id="date">{{toDate(object.date)}}</a>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Then, in your controller define a function and return a formatted date:

```
toDate = function(date){ 
  return date.getUTCDate() +"/"+ (date.getUTCMonth()+1) +"/"+ date.getUTCFullYear();
};
```

This is assuming that object.date is actually a [Date Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).